# How to call the jQuery module functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this way, I want to understand JavaScript Module Pattern With jQuery. 
I have a simple task for myself, There is one button and three jQuery functions, I want after clicking on the button, one function1 call another function2, and fucnction2 call function3 with an alert message.

My jQuery and html code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    //How to add another two functions?
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='alertScript.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="myBtn">Push</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` and where are functions?

Comment: Your example code doesn't apparently have anything to do with the module pattern. Read up on it [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myBtn").click(function() {
        console.log('ok');
        fn1();
    });
});

function fn1(){
console.log("Fn 1 Called");
fn2();
}

function fn2(){
alert("Fn 2 Called");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="myBtn">Push</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @VladSobko Cool

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnclick").click(function() {
        console.log('function1 called');
       function1();
    });
});
 function function1() {
            alert('1 call funtion2');
              console.log('function2 called');
            function2();
        }
        function function2() {
          alert('2 call funtion3');
            console.log('function3 called');
            function3();
        }
        function function3() {
          console.log('1 2 3 calling');
            alert('function 1 call function 2 and function2 call function 3');
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="btnclick">Push</button>
</body>
</html>
```